# Updating pointers in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-value

I am passing a pointer a function that updates it. However when the function returns the pointer it returns to the value it had prior to the function call.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void func(char *pSrc) {
    int x;
    for ( x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
        *pSrc++;
    }

    printf("Pointer Within Function: %p\n", pSrc  );
}

int main(void) {

    char *pSrc = "Good morning Dr. Chandra. This is Hal. I am ready for my first lesson.";

    printf("Pointer Value Before Function: %p\n", pSrc  );

    func(pSrc);

    printf("Pointer Value After Function: %p\n", pSrc  );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the output

```
Pointer Value Before Function: 0x100403050
Pointer Within Function: 0x10040305a
Pointer Value After Function: 0x100403050
```

What I was expecting was the value after the function to match the one from within the function.

I tried switching to `char **pSrc` but that did not have the desired affect.

I am sure the answer is fairly simple, but I am a recovering hardware engineer and can't seem to figure it out :-)

Comment: You need to pass the *address* of your `char *pSrc` so you can modify what `pSrc` points to (keep `char *pSrc`, pass it as `&pSrc`, and have the function take a `char **`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pointer inside the function is a copy of the passed pointer.

They both **hold** the same address but have different addresses, so changing the address held by one of them doesn't affect the other.

If you want to increment the pointer inside the function pass it's address instead, like this

```
static void func(char **pSrc) {
    int x;
    for ( x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
        (*pSrc)++;
    }    
    printf("Pointer Within Function: %p\n", pSrc  );
}
```

and

```
func(&pSrc);
```

Also, be careful not to modify the contents, because your pointer points to a string literal, and string literals cannot be modified.

Answer (score 2):

`C` uses *pass-by-value* for function parameter passing. The value of `pSrc` is just a *copy* of the `pSrc` present in `main()`, not the *same entity* as the `pSrc` from `main()`. That is why, any changes made to `pSrc` inside the function `func()`won't be reflected in `main()` (caller function).

However, all the changes to `*pSrc` will sustain.

Solution: To change the `pSrc` of `main()` from `func()`, you need to pass a pointer to `pSrc` (pointer to a pointer) from `main()` and adjust the data types accordingly. Also, in that case, please note, the `pSrc` should be modifiable (present in read-write memory). As it is currently written, the `pSrc` in `main()` is not modifiable.

Comment: C also uses pass by reference, does it not?

Comment: @ryyker is it so? how, please? Atleast, i my knowledge, it does not.

Comment: The correct statement I believe would be _With the exception of arrays and functions, C always passes arguments by value_ .  ( ***[from here](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/catam/ccatsl/manual/node50.html)*** , for example )  I understand the point of your answer, and have no real problem with it, only this one point :)

Comment: @ryyker I got your point, but I don't agree with your words. In case of arrays also, the _paramater_ itself is passed by value only. Can you change the base address of an array (considering a double pointer) from inside a function? :-)

Comment: By the same token, are you saying that if I pass a pointer to a struct that the values of the members of that struct are included?  They are not, but can be accessed via the _reference_ to location of that struct.  Here is ***[another reference](http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html)*** that goes into more detail.

Comment: @ryyker absolutely not, please don't get me wrong. I'm not a native English speaker, so my wordings may be confusing. What i try to tell is that the "value at the address" is passed by reference, but the "value" itself  (the structure pointer, or the double pointer in our case) is passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

When you give a pointer to a function, you have a copy of the reference value that you originally had.

Then, if you modify your pointer, **you're modifying a copy**.

If you want to update the original one, you need to pass it with a double pointer `**` which will let you modify the original pointer, passing a "reference to a reference" (double pointer).

Answer (score 1):

C is passing parameters by value, so it makes a copy of pSrc inside your function, and all the changes you've made are applied to a copy of pSrc. If you want to change the value of pSrc, then you should pass a pointer to pSrc, like this:

```
static void func(char **pSrc){ // pointer to char*
     int x;
     for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
         (*pSrc)++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `func` by passing `pSrc`. You think you are passing the same variable - That is `func` will operate on the same memory location when it alters `pSrc`. This is false.

`func` gets a copy of `pSrc`. The stack frame built in calling `func` will have its own `pSrc`. What is modified is its version not the calling function's.

To let `func` operate on the actual variable in main you got to pass address of `pSrc` - `&pSrc`.

Relevant concepts - Pass by Value and Pass by Reference.