# Array elements are "lost" outside the function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have a matrix in a file like:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 -9
```

where the first line indicates the square matrix order. I'm using the following code to read the file and store it into a vector (I have removed all `if` checks for sake of simplicity):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_matrix_file(const char *fname, double *vector)
{
    /* Try to open file */
    FILE *fd = fopen(fname, "r");
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fd);

    int n;
    sscanf(line, "%d", &n)

    vector = realloc(vector, n * n * sizeof *vector);
    memset(vector, 0, n * n * sizeof *vector);

    /* Reads the elements */
    int b;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        // Read the i-th line into line
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) == NULL) {
            perror("fgets");
            return(-1);
        }

        /* Reads th j-th element of i-th line into the vector */
        char *elem_ptr = line;
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++) {
            if(sscanf(elem_ptr, "%lf%n", &vector[n*i+j] , &b) != 1) {
                perror("sscanf");
                return(1);
            }
            elem_ptr += b;
        }
    }
    fclose(fd);

    /* HERE PRINTS OK */
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
        printf("%i %f\n",i, vector[i]);

    return n;
}
```

The `read_matrix_file` receives a filename and an `array` of `doubles` and fill the array, returning the matrix order. The expected usage can be seen in this code block.

```
int main(void)
{

    const char *fname = "matrix.txt";
    double *vector = malloc(sizeof * vector);

    int n = read_matrix_file(fname, vector);

    /* Here prints junk */
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
        printf("%i %f\n",i, vector[i]);

    free(vector);
}
```

The issue is, the `printf` works fine inside the `read_matrix_file` but seems invalid in `main`.

I'm allocating the array outside the function and passing it by "reference", but I'm very suspecious of `realloc`, unfortunatelly I don't know how to fix or a better approach.

Comment: Google *Updating pointers in a function in C* - you need to pass vector by `**`.

Comment: Remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*. That means their values are *copied* into the functions local argument variables. Modifying a copy (like assigning to it) will not modify the original. Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: Also note that you should never assign back to the pointer you pass to [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc). If `realloc` fails and return a null pointer, then you lose the original pointer and have a memory leak.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating pointers in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658614/updating-pointers-in-a-function)

Comment: What is `start`? Is it supposed to be `elem_ptr `?

Comment: @WeatherVane indeed. fixed.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I don't think is exactly equal, since the `realloc` here is absent in the duplicate candidate.

Comment: It does not matter if the pointer is modified via `++` or via a call to `realloc`. It is exactly the same mechanism.

Comment: @Gerhardh can you please point me some document to learn more about the internal `realloc` mechanism?

Comment: Which internal `realloc` mechanism? It is about modifying a variable in a function. It does not matter if you do this with `malloc`, `realloc`, `++`, `=&other_variable` or any other machanism changing the value of a variable. It is only about adding another level of indirection to the variable. If you do not have the address of the variable outside your function you cannot change it. You can only change a copy of the value which will be thrown away after you return.

Comment: regarding: `vector = realloc(vector, n * n * sizeof *vector);` and `int read_matrix_file(const char *fname, double *vector)`  The call to `realloc()` can/will change where the callers' `vector` is pointing.  To successfully do that, must pass the address of `vector` so the signature should be: `int read_matrix_file(const char *fname, double **vector)`  Then, all references to `vector` need to be modified  (except the call to `realloc()` ) to properly de-reference that parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reallocating memory inside `read_matrix_file()` and storing the elements of the matrix in that memory region. But when you come out of the function, since the pointer `vector`is a local variable, its new value is lost when you leave the function.

When you come back inside `main()` vector still points to the (now likely invalid) memory region that you had previously allocated with `malloc()`.

You should either allocate large enough memory before calling `read_matrix_file` or pass a double pointer (**) if you want to modify the pointer and see the change reflected back in `main()`

What I meant is something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_matrix_file(const char *fname, double **p_vector)
{
    /* Try to open file */
    FILE *fd = fopen(fname, "r");
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fd);

    int n;
    sscanf(line, "%d", &n);

    *p_vector = realloc(*p_vector, n * n * sizeof **p_vector);
    double *vector = *p_vector;

    memset(vector, 0, n * n * sizeof *vector);

    /* Reads the elements */
    int b;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        // Read the i-th line into line
        if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fd) == NULL) {
            perror("fgets");
            return(-1);
        }

        /* Reads th j-th element of i-th line into the vector */
        char *elem_ptr = line;
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++) {
            if(sscanf(elem_ptr, "%lf%n", &vector[n*i+j] , &b) != 1) {
                perror("sscanf");
                return(1);
            }
            elem_ptr += b;
        }
    }
    fclose(fd);

    /* HERE PRINTS OK */
    for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
        printf("%i %f\n",i, vector[i]);

    return n;
}
```

In main, call it with:

```
int n = read_matrix_file(fname, &vector);
```

EDIT: Please note that this code does not handle the failure of `realloc()` properly.

Comment: passing a `**` how can I handle the realloc? The problem is, I don't know how large my matrix will be  before read the file. Any other better strategies?

Comment: @Lin You handle the size in the same way as before. Instead of `vector` you need to use `*vector`

Comment: I think you missed `*p_vector` in `realloc` first parameter

Comment: Just curious, why are you allocating memory with `malloc` in the main function and then `realloc` inside the function? Why not just `malloc` inside `read_matrix_file`?

Comment: Why not just use 'malloc()' in the called function?   Because the (already set values in`vector`) need to be kept and `realloc()` will keep those values

Comment: @user3629249 In this specific case, the OP doesn't seem to care about any of the data that was in the buffer before the `realloc`. I mean he doesn't even initialize it after the `malloc`.

Comment: indeed. I don't care (and I don't know) anything about the data structure before I open the file and read the first line (that I do inside the `read_matrix_file`), I just `malloc` beforehand to keep the pointer address in call block. Any other ways to accomplish that?

Comment: @Lin In that case, you could simply pass in a (pointer-to-) NULL pointer and do a `malloc()` within `read_matrix_file` instead of `realloc()`, as suggested by @alrevuelta