# Dynamic arrays clarification in C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

I create a dynamic `int` array and I read from a file numbers and passing them in the array using `malloc` and `realloc`, when the while in the function is finished the printing is correct but when I go back to the `main` after the function `readNames` the `printf` prints addresses instead of the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readNames(FILE *, int *, char **, int *);

void readNames(FILE *fpN, int *numbers, char **names, int *total){
    char sentence[512];

     while (fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), fpN)){
    
    char *token = strtok(sentence, " "); //grab the number
    numbers[*total] = atoi(token); //add it to the array
        
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    
    //names[*total] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
    //strcpy(names[*total], token);
    
    (*total)++;
    // printf("TOTAL:%d",*total);

    numbers = (int*)realloc(numbers,*(total+1)*sizeof(int)); //allocate more space for the int array
     //names = (char**)(realloc(names, (*total+1)*sizeof(char*)));
     //printf("%d", sizeof(names));
     //allocate more space for the string array
   
 }
 
printf("%d ", (*(numbers+2)));
printf("%d ", (numbers[1]));

printf("%d ", (numbers[2]));

}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *fpN = NULL;
    FILE *fpG = NULL;

    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Wrong arguments");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((fpN = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
        { // check if the file exists
            printf("File not found!");
            exit(0);
        }

    if ((fpG = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL)
        { // check if the file exists
            printf("File not found!");
            exit(0);
        }

int total = 0;
int *numbers = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); //array will initially have 1 element

char **names = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
readNames(fpN, numbers, names, &total);

printf("%d ", (numbers[0]));
printf("Enter");
printf("%d ", (numbers[1]));

printf("%d ", (numbers[2]));
printf("Enter");

    // char sentence[512];

// int diagram[total][total];
// memset(diagram, 0 , sizeof(diagram));
//  while (fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), fpG)){
//     char *token = strtok(sentence, " ->\n:\n");
//         int row = atoi(token);
//             while(token = strtok(NULL, " ->\n:\n")){
//                 int col = atoi(token);
//                  diagram[row][col] = atoi(strtok(NULL, " ->\n:\n"));
                 
//             }
//  }

}
```

Comment: "//array will initially have 1 element"  When do you think, this will change? Remember: You are passing `numbers` to your function "by value", i.e. whatever you assign within that function will  not be visible outside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating pointers in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658614/updating-pointers-in-a-function)

Comment: @Gerhardh. But my number array is a pointer and inside the method I am reallocating memory so i can store more numbers

Comment: No. You pass a copy of that pointer and only change that copy. After returning from the function, the copy is not existing any more. Also the old value of the pointer might not be valid any more after you passed that address to `realloc`. See the duplicate link I provided.

Comment: Ok so let's say i pass the address of the int *array, inside the function what would the parameters be, it would be like funct(int **array)? how would i acess the array elements?

Comment: It would be `int**numbers` and you could use `int *local_numbers = *numbers;`. Then do all your updates to `local_numbers` and before you return, do `*numbers = local_numbers;`. That avoids having to use an extra `*` everytime you use `numbers`.

Comment: No, you can also add some larger chunk every time and only realloc when you reach the new limit. As you did with 2 elements at the beginning

Comment: @Gerhardh With char **array it would work the same way?    warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     char **local_names = **names;

Comment: Obviously not. `**names` is a single `char` (or a `char*` if you updated parameter list) and you want to initialize a pointer to pointer to `char`. You would need `char***names` and `char **local_names = *names;`

Comment: my parameters will be void readNames(FILE *fpN, int **numbers, char **names) ? and then the rest you said about the code?

Comment: No, as I wrote, it should be `char***names`. You want a pointer to an array of strings. That is `char**names` in `main`. And in your function you want to modify that pointer. That is another `*`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, it is so frustrating with the pointers you helped me so much thank you again!!!!!

Comment: `*(total+1)` -> `(*total+1)` ?

Comment: "FIle not found!" is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Replace `printf("File not found!");` with `perror(argv[1]);`. Errors belong on stderr and should include details.

Comment: Looking at the code in comments, your delimiters for `strtok` look strange: `" ->\n:\n"`. There is no need to add `\n` twice. Also do you search for arrows (`"->"`) or for `'-'` and `'>'` separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your pointers "by value", that means a copy of the current value is passed to the function.
Whatever you do to that copy inside your function, will be lost once you return from the function.

Furthermore the allocated memory you passed, may be invalid after calling `realloc`.

Instead of passing your pointers, you must pass the addresses of your pointer variables:
(Also note a fixed typo in the size used for `realloc`).

```c
void readNames(FILE *fpN, int **numbers, char ***names, int *total){
    char *my_numbers = *numbers;
    char **my_names = *names;

    char sentence[512];

    while (fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), fpN)) {
    
      char *token = strtok(sentence, " "); //grab the number
      my_numbers[*total] = atoi(token); //add it to the array
        
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    
      //my_names[*total] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
      //strcpy(my_names[*total], token);
    
      (*total)++;
      // printf("TOTAL:%d",*total);

      my_numbers = realloc(my_numbers, (*total+1)*sizeof(int)); //allocate more space for the int array
     //my_names = realloc(my_names, (*total+1)*sizeof(char*));
     //printf("%zu", sizeof(my_names));  // << this will only print size of a pointer. 
     //allocate more space for the string array
  }

  // Copy local pointers back to caller's variables
  *numbers = my_numbers;
  *names = my_names;
 
  printf("%d ", (*(numbers+2)));
  printf("%d ", (numbers[1]));
  printf("%d ", (numbers[2]));

}
```

Then update your caller:

```c
    int total = 0;
    int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int)); //array will initially have 1 element
    char **names = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    readNames(fpN, &numbers, &names, &total);
```

You could improve that code a bit more:

- You allocate memory for next element in advance. That means you have 1 unused element allocated. You could initialize your pointers to `NULL` and only `realloc` when you found a new line to parse.
- Unless you have a specific need to handle the 2 arrays you pass, separately, it would be better to create a struct for both values and pass only one pointer to an array of these structs.

With these 2 changes your code would look like this:

```c
struct element {
    int number;
    char *name;
};

void readNames(FILE *fpN, struct elemen **elements, int *total){
    struct element *my_elements = *elements;

    char sentence[512];

    while (fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), fpN)) {
       my_elements= realloc(my_elements, (*total+1)  *sizeof(*my_elements)); //allocate space for the new entry
   
      char *token = strtok(sentence, " "); //grab the number
      my_elements[*total].number = atoi(token); //add it to the array
        
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
      //my_elements[*total].name = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
      //strcpy(my_elements[*total].name, token);
    
      (*total)++;
      // printf("TOTAL:%d",*total);
  }

  // Copy local pointer back to caller's variable
  *elements= my_elements;
 
  printf("%d ", my_elements[1].number);
  printf("%d ", my_elements[2].number);
}
```

and the caller:

```c
    int total = 0;
    struct element *elements = NULL;  // Allcation will be done later
    readNames(fpN, &elements, &total);
```

Comment: Note that you can safely initialize `numbers` and `names` to `NULL`. The `realloc()` accepts that. Next reorder the loop to first `realloc` and next fill the entries

Comment: I know. I just added it as further optimization as we waste a bit memory with the current approach.

Comment: You do not know how much I appreciate this. Pointers is kinda difficult for a beginner, thank you so much