# "pointer may be used after free" error doesn't see that I am allocating memory to the pointer

Tags: c

This is a short example of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void m(void * x) {
    x = malloc(100);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *ptr;
    m(ptr);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    free(ptr);

    m(ptr);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I am allocating memory to a pointer from inside a function.
The compiler apparently has no idea that I am allocating memory, and also error checking it.

So there is 0 chance of the memory being un-allocated and un-freeable before the second free.

Yet I get the error that the pointer MAY be used after free.

To fix this I have to keep spamming `ptr = NULL;` after every free;

Initially I thought I could give an uninitialized variable to a function, but apparently not, so I had to assign NULL to the initial declaration.

However, I assumed the latter ptr instances had some residual address inside of them.

Is this a problem of a function not accepting freshly-freed/uninitialized pointers, or the compiler being unable to understand that I malloc and check the pointer between frees, or both, or something else?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that arguments to functions are passed *by value*. Which means the value in the call is *copied* to the functions *local* argument variable. If you modify the local variable, like assigning to it, will be lost once the function returns and the life-time of the local variable ends.

Comment: Also remember that the size you pass to `malloc` is the size in *bytes*, not "array elements".

Comment: I don't know where these two misunderstandings come from, but any decent beginners book, tutorial or class should have taught you both of these things. What resources are you using to learn C?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating pointers in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658614/updating-pointers-in-a-function)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think mine is a fair misconception since one can casually change chars via pointers, and double pointers are rare unless you are doing arrays. I guess I found out the hard way why malloc functions return a pointer instead of taking it as an argument. I changed my functions now to return pointers because I still can't mentally wrap my head around pointers to pointers. Can't think of a single standard library function that takes a **, and you need to give it a &pointer. Actually, I think I remember one, but can't remember the name.

Comment: _"Can't think of a single standard library function that takes a `**`...."_ Sometimes you see function signatures with `*arg[]`, which is just another spelling of `**arg` (in function prototypes); `main` itself takes a `char **argv`. Many string handling functions in the Standard Library take a `char **endptr` argument which is the address of a pointer provided by the caller which is updated in a function call; the entire `strto` family of string conversion functions uses such a double pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters in C are passed by *value*. `x` is a local variable and what you assign in the function is not visible outside the `m` function scope.

To modify the pointer passed you need to pass the reference to that pointer -ie pointer to pointer.

```
void m(int **x) {
    *x = malloc(100);
}
```

(side note): 100 is the size in ***`char`s*** not in `int`s

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problem understanding or visualizing pointers, use pen and paper to *draw* it.

For example lets say we have the code

```
const char *pointer = "foo";
```

If we draw it, it will be something like this:

```
+---------+      +-------+
| pointer | ---> | "foo" |
+---------+      +-------+
```

Now lets add a pointer to the pointer:

```
const char **pointer_pointer = &pointer;  // Using the "pointer-to" operator
```

Then now we instead have this:

```
+-----------------+      +---------+      +-------+
| pointer_pointer | ---> | pointer | ---> | "foo" |
+-----------------+      +---------+      +-------+
```

That is, the variable `pointer_pointer` is pointing to the variable `pointer`. And the variable `pointer` is pointing to the string literal `"foo"`.